# Identify cause of cascading trigger

Tags: triggers, db2, cascade, db2-luw

DB2

I am getting SQLCODE-724, indicating cascading trigger at 17th level, and I suppose that some procedure called by a procedure called by a trigger updates a field that calls the trigger.

How would I create a monitor to help identify the sequence in which procedures/triggers are being called so I can put an end to this cascading-trigger problem?

Comment: Db2-server operating-system ?  Db2 version and fixpack ?

Comment: Windows 2012 R2 / DB2 10.5 FP7

Comment: An event monitor might not be the optimal approach in this case. If this is a new symptom, then code inspection of changed artefacts should help if you have source code for all involved routines and triggers.  A different approach: consider using  db2pdcfg -catch..., with a custom db2cos script that captures useful db2pd output when the -724 symptom happens.  If you are intent on using an event monitor, then an 'event monitor for activities' may help, though you need to be aware of run time overheads. There's a learning curve. Hence code inspection may be more pragmatic.

Comment: I am not the developer, and this is in a huge application that has hundreds of stored procedures and triggers. I have already traced through the procedures (some having over a thousand lines of code to read) called by the trigger but without yet being able to identify the problem. My hope is to enable a monitor temporarily in my test DB just long enough to run through this process once and then analyze the output and search for statements that repeat, possibly indicating recursion or cascading trigger. Capturing -724 data after it occurs will not help; I need to capture how we get there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DB2 profiler written by Serge Rielau:

- More than a TRACE. Extending the SQL PL Profiler to do tracing https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/tracing?lang=en
- Reality Check: SQL PL Profiler and plan explain with actual row counts https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/sql_pl_profiler_and_plan_explain_with_actual_row_counts23?lang=en

Also, you can put a logger tool in the code, like log4db2 https://github.com/angoca/log4db2

With these tools, you can identify what is happening in the code, and identify the source of the problem.